# Elasticsearch special character issues after upgrading Spring 2.5 to 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I was fixing a bug which came through the upgrade from Spring 2.5 to Spring 3.0.
Now before in Spring 2.5 we had custom method from a repo that extended the ElasticsearchRepository interface,
and in the method we passed some parameters which were escaped beforehand.For example

```
 searchItemsBySomeParameter(projectId, ElasticMyClass.escape(searchParam), language, 
 dbPageable);
```

the ElasticMyClass.escape does append // to the special character, so in the case of '-' it becomes '\-'

It was working fine.
After the upgrade to Spring 3.0 it started giving problems each time we tried to search with special character,

namely

```
"caused_by":{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[27:53] [bool] failed to parse field 
[must]","caused_by":{"type":"x_content_parse_exception","reason":"[27:53] [bool] failed to 
parse field [should]","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unrecognized 
character escape '-' (code 45)\n at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream);
```

the i simply removed the ElasticMyClass.escape method, and now it seems to work.My question is ,i know that Spring 2.5 used 7.xx Elastic client,
whereas Spring 3 uses Elastic 8 something client.I tried to go through the Release notes to find what did change,
but i could not find anything, does anybody know what changed and in which version so that escaping is no longer needed ?

Comment: as per my understanding, escape charchter should be before the special charchter and not after charachter. it should be `\\-` and not `-\\ `